# Client side form validation rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, format

**Issue:** My client side rails form input format validation won't work how the regex is set up to.

**I have the following rails form input:**

```
<%= form.text_field :twitter_link, 
    class: "form-control", 
    required: true, 
    pattern: "^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+\/status\/\d+(?:\/\/?)?$", 
    title: "Twitter Comment URL" %>
```

When i enter the correct format, it won't validate and the "enter correct format" message appears.

**The following regex in my model validates for the param:**

```
/\A^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+\/status\/\d+(?:\/\/?)?\z/
```

As you can see I have made a few changes from my model side validates to see if it would work.  I have tried a few other things but nothing has solved.

Works fine for my model side validation but won't work client side.  Is there something I need to change for it to work?

I am making a client side validation so I can have a custom message for the single text_field without the need for a flash or redirect.  Any who, since I have a nested form 3 ways deep, I am having issues having the alert appear as a flash.now without needing to reload the page using a plain flash.  Not sure what the issue is but this seems to be a good alternative.

How can I fix this so the regex works with the input text_field?

Comment: Are you using jquery form-validation?

Comment: This is a built in feature for html i believe.  When i use something simple like "[0-9]", it works in validating numbers only.  Is there a certain format needed for this other than the regular regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a singly quotation instead of the double seems to do the trick.

```
<%= form.text_field :twitter_link, 
    class: "form-control", 
    required: true, 
    pattern: '^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:(?:www|m)\.)?twitter\.com\/\w+\/status\/\d+(?:\/\/?)?$', 
    title: "Twitter Comment URL" %>
```

Not sure why i didn't try this before because i have ran into similar issues in the past with double vs single